Deleting JWT on log-out
I recently started using JWT and one Big question is that " we can't really delete a token on demand ?"
Doubt: As of my info JWT are stored in cookies as hashes, so even if a website clears user cookies when you log-out, this token is still valid until its expiry if you have stored it somewhere.
Issue: If some how i make a request and send this token to server even after logging out it will be validated.
So how is this issue managed ?
Or am i missing some thing here ?

When I was facing this issue, I managed it by creating a blackList in the cache. Then I was checking if the token exist in that cache. Also to not overload the cache, you should implement clean up mechanism

So you will create a black list of these tokens in DB, right?
But I am using these tokens instead of sessions just because I don't want to query my DB again. I am just authenticating user if i found the JWT valid. Then I am trying to clear JWT on logout.

I use inmemory cache, not db

If i create a blackList in my system's cache, this list won't be present on other systems so if someone tries to use token from other device, it won't prevent them from accessing.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
